# Sitemap - How to extract .xml.gz URLs

Tags: xml, url, sitemap, gzip

I have a excel file with around 3K sitemap urls (URLs .xml.gz format) Could anyone help me in extracting all the links available in the .xml.gz URLs at once?

Each .xml.gz URLs contains around 25K URLs within it!!

Thanks in advance,
Sanjay

Answer (score 1):

`.xml.gz` isn't an Excel file, but an gz-compressed (archived) xml-sitemap. Everything you should do to get urls from the sitemap into Excel is:

- decompress the archive, take something like 7zip,
- import xml into Excel, like on screenshot (my Excel is german, so look at screenshot and try to find your way)

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply! But I dont see any suchn options in my excel.

Comment: You should add it firstly